# #include file inserts in body not head

Tags: html, iis-7, ssi

I have the following html page which refers to an include file for my generic head content. However, rather than inserting the contents of 'head.html' in to the head element, it is being added to the body element.

I have no script errors. This occurs in FF, Chrome or IE. I have tried removing all content from the head.html except a single trace and it still gets included in the body. Could there be another framework that is interfering with the rendering of the head, I assumed it was simply going to get the include file and dump it in exactly where it is referenced so quite how this is occurring seems rather weird to me.

tia.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!--#include file="includes/head.html" -->

{ rest of non-generic head content }

 </head>

  <body class="animated fadeIn" style="" id="users">  ..............
```

Comment: You are using [Server Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) and, as the name suggests, it a server-side technology that has nothing to do with the browser. I don't know what your web server is (or even if you have one) but the first debugging step is to hit Ctrl+U to see the HTML generated by the server.

Comment: I did a quick test on my own website and your example works fine here. So there must be something else going wrong, something you're not showing. Is it a standard setting where the file extension is `.shtml`, or did you change the server settings to allow all extensions? Also, what's the contents of `head.html`?

Comment: Yes, this is an .shtml file, served by IIS 7.
The content of head.html is just stylesheets mainly but this behaviour occurs regardless of the contents of the file (i.e. if I put in 'hello' that gets inserted in to the body not the head.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - of course that is the first step, that is how I know there is the problem!

Comment: Well, you wouldn't believe how many users here overlook that, or inspect the generated DOM tree (with Firebug or Chrome console) rather than the HTML source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that was a thing of pure evil.

It transpired the include file was encoded as UTF-8 and that was breaking the correct SSI behaviour.
Changing the file to ANSI fixed it.

Comment: I'd understand that a UTF-8 **BOM** in the middle of the file would confuse the browser but it's unbelievable that it makes the server output out of synch. Well, that's for reporting back.

Comment: Haha, another argument for "UTF-8 BOMs are evil". Anyway, but I can imagine that a BOM, in its guise as a ZWNBSP, counts as non-whitespace to the browser, and therefore it shouldn't be in the head, and the browser ends the head and starts the body implicitly before inserting it.